# How to load a file in Pig that has a variable number of fields

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have an input file which contains records as follows:

```
Movie1     Actor 1, Actor 2, Actor 3, ......, Actor n
Movie2     Actor 1, Actor 2,.......Actor n
```

I want to load this data into a bag in Pig

```
 movies = LOAD 'movies.imdb' AS (......);
```

I am not sure how to fill up my "AS" field because the records in my input file may have variable number of fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
movies = LOAD 'movies.imdb' USING PigStorage(',');
```

If the records don't have fixed fields, using `AS` won't be possible

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just have a clarification, in my input file, movie name and actor list is separated by a tab whereas actor list is separated by ",", so will i be able to load the data correctly using this load command?

Comment: In that case I'd use tabs so:
movies = LOAD 'movies.imdb' USING PigStorage('\t');

Then use the STRSPLIT function to create a tuple of actors

Comment: Then the fields can be referred using $0,$1,$2 etc.